# Why Grails is creating one session per http request?

Tags: session, grails, tomcat7

I have a java client that do HTTP requests to a grails 2.5.5 server on tomcat7 instance.

The strange thing is that the tomcat7 or grails creates one session per request to a grails controller.

I've tried to use:

```
static scope = 'singleton'
```

But didn't work!

Someone knows what is happening?

Tomcat7 creates on session per http request or is the grails controller configuration?

Comment: What kind of session are you talking about?  HTTP, database, other?  I'm assuming HTTP session.  If so, what are you using for authentication and session management?

Comment: I'm using grails default session(HttpSession).
I read more of this behavior and i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691709/grails-osiv-stop-open-session-in-view-filter-for-static-resources). I'm testing now to remove some actions in filters to prevent grails to create a session to every request.
I think the problem is that grails creates new session when a request enter in some filter.

Comment: It sounds like you may be confused about how HTTP sessions work.  If you write an HTTP client that calls your Grails app and your client isn't doing anything special with the session, each request is supposed to result in a new session because each request is a whole new thing.  There is no way for the server to know that the requests came from the same process unless the client is coded to deal with that.

Comment: None of this has anything to do with controller scope or filters.

Comment: If i send the JSESSIONID from grails to Java Client and save it on Java and send it in Cookies Property like the chrome saves the JSESSIONID in Cookies....Will this work?

Comment: I found a first non great solution: 
Create a **def afterInterceptor = [action: this.&invalidateSession]** to invalidate the sessions that don't need session object.

Comment: I think the problem was listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348731/grails-session-creation-on-how-to-prevent-it). The Joshua's Moore comment seems consistent. if i use session object in the filter, grails creates new session.

Comment: I don't think there is a problem.  You're not actually establishing or using a session in your client, so your server isn't going to recognize one either.  But no, this has nothing to do with controller scope or filters, other than that you can alter the session from a filter, or a controller.  I would advise you to look at what your client provides for session management and go from there!

Comment: Thanks Daniel... i'm searching more!

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this solution:

1. Didn't change the request(GET) in Java client side.
2. I removed the request of URL in my filters.
3. Put the **render** call in the end of the grails action (i forgot it :/), so grails could not give to client the response and trate the request as a GET view request.

Thanks for all comments guys!